# OData filter on enum

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to use OData with a .NET Core WebApi project. Since I want to control the format of the output I'm taking a probably not very conventional approach and in my action I'm receiving a ODataQueryOptions input that I'm applying to my data source - a CosmosDb collection exposed via EF Core.
Code wise I have something like in the startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.AddOData();
        ....
}
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ....

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            /* tried even
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(ODataUriResolver), sp => new StringAsEnumResolver());
            });
            */
            endpoints.Filter();
        });
        ...
}
```

The controller is very simple:

```
namespace Backend.Activity.Api.Controllers
{

[Route("api/activities/search")]
[ApiController]
public class SearchController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ActivityContext _db;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public SearchController(ActivityContext db, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _db = db;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]        
    public async Task<List<ActivitySummaryDTO>> GetActivities(ODataQueryOptions<Domain.Models.Activity> opts)
    {
        try
        {
            var odataResult = opts.ApplyTo(_db.Activities.AsQueryable());
            var activities = odataResult as IQueryable<Domain.Models.Activity>;
            var activitiesDto= _mapper.Map<List<ActivitySummaryDTO>>(activities);                
            return activitiesDto;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
}
```

this works just fine if I go and do a filter on properties that are strings, GUIDs or numbers. Whenever I'm trying to run a filter on a fields that's an enum (they are stored in CosmosDB as strings) I run into problems...

I've been trying to use filters such as `$filter=MyPropertyEnum eq 'enumValue'`, but got error: `Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'Activity.Domain.Enums.MyPropertyEnum'.`

I've been trying to Google for solutions, but wasn't able to find any so far... any help or suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks!

Comment: May be you can see this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20404),hope it can help you.

Comment: @yinqiu that was it... I can't believe it :| worst part is that they don't plan to implement it in 3.x.x so I had to take a RC.... thank you so much! Please add a reply with this so I can accept it and close this issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed for Cosmos in EF Core 5.0. Currently, this feature is not fixed in 3.xx.

May be you can see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20404) link,hope it can help you.